# Computation of the resultant through subresultant pseudoremainder sequences algorithm

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, principal-ideal-domains, euclidean-algorithm, resultant

Let $f,g$ be polynomials of $\mathbb{k}[x]$ where $\mathbb{k}$ is a field. The resultant of $f,g$, $Res(f,g)$, is an element of $\mathbb{k}$ which by definition equals the determinant of the Sylvester matrix of these polynomials. It can be shown that  it equals the product of all the differences between the roots of $f,g$ (some of them may lie in a field extension) times a power product of their leading coefficients.

In wikipedia it says that the resultant can also be computed through a variant of the Euclidean al-gorithm called [*subresultant pseudoremainder sequences*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), producing a generalization of the Bezout's identity:
$$
a(x)f(x)+b(x)g(x)=Res(f,g)\in\mathbb{k}
$$
**My question is:** what is the *"subresultant pseudoremainder sequences"* algorithm, how can it be applied and how can we find the polynomials $a(x)$, $b(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend the following book for the subresultant algorithm and related results. In you will find the theory behind the subresultants and a full description of the quadratic time algorithm to compute them and notes on the bit complexity of the algorithm.

[Algorithms in Real Algebraic Geometry](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540330981)

Comment: this is an interesting reference indeed. Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: That book version is from 2006. An updated 2016 version can be downloaded for free from
https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/marie-francoise.roy/bpr-ed2-posted3.html